# TurtleBot Moves in Real Environment and Gazebo World

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, turtlebot-apps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I build environment in gazbo, and run make turtlebot move in it and draw map in rviz.

What I want to do know, is to give turtlebot move commands so it move in real environment and move in gazebo and draw map in Rviz all at the same time ..

What i found is that  command go to gazebo or real robot but not the two

here is all [Topics] run (/upfiles/13653369789478456.png)

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60158/turtlebot-moves-in-real-environment-and-gazebo-world/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-04-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run both robots (simulation and real) in their own name spaces..
The robot in gazebo and the real robot can subscribe to the same Twist topic (e.g. /cmd_vel).

If you do this, then both robots will move. You will need to pick one of them to generate the map depending on what it is that you're actually trying to accomplish.

There are no guarantees that the robots will be in the same place when the sequence of Twist messages have been executed due to things like friction and simulation approximations.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-04-09**:
Thank I will try this ....
:

do you know the scale of Gazebo Grid?!

Thanks

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-04-10**:
Not sure what you mean..  but this link may provide you with more information to help ask the question (or maybe even to answer it!) http://gazebosim.org/api/1.4.0/classgazebo_1_1rendering_1_1Grid.html#details